# Matlab vector assistance

Tags: matlab, function, vector, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a column vector in matlab based on two 64x64 double vectors, and iterate through each element in the vector and apply an equation to create a new vector, which will then be applied. Here is my code

```
for i=1:4096,

vector1 = v1(:); %instead of copying the vector this created a 4096X1 double rather than 64X64 for some reason, same with vector2
vector2 = v1(:);
vector1(i) = vector1(i) + 0.05*vector2(i); %for each element in vector1 apply equation to update values.
end
v1(:) = vector1(:); % replace v1 with the new vector1 created on the equation applied
```

As far as I see this should work, however instead of creating a 64*64 vector a 1*4096 vector is created and I am getting a mismatch error because the vectors are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting vector is a column vector because that's the output of [*linear indexing*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) (indexing with a only a single subscript). It's also worth noting that the conversion to a column vector is redundant, linear indexing does that implicitly.

If you want the final result to be a 64x64 matrix, initialize the result array with the appropriate size to begin with:

```
result = zeros(size(v1)); %// Same dimensions as v1, i.e 64-by-64
```

and let MATLAB automatically convert linear indices into the corresponding position in the result matrix. Alternatively, you can use `reshape`, for example:

```
result = reshape(v1, 64, 64);
```

In addition, I believe that your loop's logic is indeed broken in more than one place:

1. You're overwriting the values of `vector1` and `vector2` in each iteration. Put the their initialization lines *before* the loop.
2. You're assigning the wrong values into `vector2`... shouldn't it be `vector = v2(:)` or something?

The final loop should look like this:

```
result = zeros(size(v1));
for k = 1:numel(v1),
    result(k) = v1(k) + 0.05 * v2(k);
end
```

Comment: Yeah I agree your way is easier, however, it must be done using iterations for some reason. The v2 value was indeed wrote down here incorrectly, as for the vector it is creating a 1*4096 vector for some reason instead of a 64*64

Answer (score 0):

```
vector1 = v1;
for i=1:64
    for j = 1:64
        vector1(i, j) = vector1(i, j) + 0.05*v1(i, j);
    end
end
v1 = vector1;     % or v1 = vector1(:, :); if you prefer
```

No vector2 matrix is needed for this process.